# How can I specify the Hardware Status Line with a command parameter?

Tags: gnu-screen

I've read the docs, but can't find how to specify the hardstatus as a command parameter. I only figure out how to do it in the config file or when screen has started.

Any pointers as to how I can do this?

Comment: This would be more on-topic on [unix.se]. A first thought (untested): maybe you could set the hardstatus in the configuration file to an environment variable and then on the command line first set that variable and them call screen?

Comment: GNU Screen is platform agnostic and you also have a dedicated gnu-screen tag here. Also, I don't want to touch the configuration file, cause I want a simple command that works no matter what system I connect to, quickly, which would include not issuing extra command to deal with the configuration file.

Comment: You may have noticed that the [tag wiki for gnu-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu-screen/info) contains a list at the bottom of sites that may be a better fit for screen questions. Unix & Linux is on that list, but also Super User if you want to make it platform agnostic. I'm not saying that it is forbidden to ask on Stack Overflow (although the question is not very programming-related), just that it may be a good idea to try one of those other sites.